# igdlh64.inf modify custom resolution

Tags: driver, intel

I have some dead pixels in top couple of rows of my cheap Win 10 tablet. To alleviate that, I wanted to use the custom resolution option in Intel graphics management panel, however, I cannot choose advanced options in the custom resolutions options and it is driving me crazy.

I remembered Intel GFX drivers used some `*.inf` to enable some options and I believe it is in `igdlh64.inf`.

Has any of you  tried to modify this or have some knowledge on this (and no there is not a documentation provided anywhere)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTD Calculator (http://www.avsforum.com/forum/26-home-theater-computers/947830-custom-resolution-tool-intel-graphics-easier-overscan-correction.html) did the job for me.

Using it I was able to create valid EDIDs and add them to by modifying [NonEDIDMode_AddSwSettings] category in the said inf file(simply modify total number of DTD and add your EDID, do not forget to add 2 Bytes of flags 37 01).

If you need further step by step instructions or detailed explanations of fields please do check https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/custom-resolutions-on-intel-graphics

Or you can try your luck with registry hack option of the DTD calculator, as well, did not work for me though.